# Google reCAPTCHA in China

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

My site is using Google reCAPTCHA control but I am hearing its being block in 
China, Is there anyway around this I see there is some people reporting that changing the API to https://www.recaptcha.net works in China?

> Anyone try this because I see it still going out to google?

```
string apiUrl = "https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}";
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, google things are not stable in China as it can be blocked anytime.
From Baidu threads, it also mentioned that sometime google recaptcha works, sometime it doesn't.
https://www.v2ex.com/t/492752 (Chinese)

In programming world ,unstable function means useless or more code for dealing with exception.

If you really need to use google recaptcha,
you would better test properly using VPN (IP in China) first.

Here are some options you can consider,

1. You can use alternative captcha

   Google will tell you various captcha.
2. Build your own captcha

[Open Source Invisible reCAPTCHA alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845255/open-source-invisible-recaptcha-alternatives)

3. Use proxy web server(nginx) to send and receive data to or from google recaptcha

Comment: Another good alternative is [hCaptcha](https://www.hcaptcha.com/). Cloudflare have a nice [blog post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/moving-from-recaptcha-to-hcaptcha/) about this as well.

Comment: @JvR You should make your comment about hCaptcha an answer by itself.

Comment: Guys, I don't want to promote any certain service. The above option 1 already have covered "can use alternative captcha". Also be aware of that not only google but any popular service can be blocked anytime.

Answer (score 19):

As google says in his assistance page, you should use this domain "www.recaptcha.net" instead "www.google.com" on the api call.

- First, replace src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" with
  src="https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js"
- After that, apply the same to everywhere else that uses "www.google.com/recaptcha/" on your site.

Obtained from: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-use-recaptcha-globally

Edit: to clarify on some of the comments, while if you try it outside of china yes you do get references to `gstatic.com` but if you try this in china, any references to `gstatic.com` are replaced with `gstatic.cn` (don't forget to add it to your SCP). So this solution is still valid.

Comment: This used to work, but today it's not anymore. We migrated away from google recaptcha and now use Botdetect (captcha.com).

Comment: Good to know. Thanks @johey

Comment: Tried this but the code at recaptcha.net contains a call to code at gstatic.com which contains calls to google.com. Can't see how this really helps.

Comment: @TonySmith did you try it within China? it worked for me at least via a VPN (all gstatic.com calls were sent to gstatic.cn instead, which didn't seem to get blocked)

Comment: Just to explicitly clarify the edit at the bottom: for the reason pointed out there, some sites that check to see if content is censored in China will falsely indicate that `recaptcha.net` is not accessible, since they resolve `gstatic.com` instead of `gstatic.cn`.

Answer (score 1):

I have shared the solution to this problem by using cURL.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63568516/11910869

**cURL** acts as a **middle man** between the client and the server. So even if **google.com/recaptcha** can not be accessed by the client because it is blocked by the service provider, cURL can act as the proxy to send the **HTTP requests** and get the **response**.