# Using reCAPTCHA globally

Tags: recaptcha

I am trying to use reCAPTCHA globally by following the instructions present at https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-use-recaptcha-globally . However, it is not working for me.

I replaced all the occurrences of "https://www.google.com/recaptcha" with "https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha" but what I noticed is it is still referring to google.com internally.

https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js is making a call to https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/TPiWapjoyMdQOtxLT9_b4n2W/recaptcha__en.js and it is internally referring to google.com host.

Looks like ReCaptcha code is broken to me. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Are you loading the recaptcha.net script from a location which has access to google.com? I have a feeling this does some geolocating to give you an appropriate CDN location, and if you have access it'll use the gstatic.com host.

Comment: This is likely one of the reasons for the comment in the recaptcha.net script `/* PLEASE DO NOT COPY AND PASTE THIS CODE. */` - this will be the latest stable cached script resolved for the requester's location.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by some comments, google's system choose the best URL, you can't force it to get from recaptcha.net. Trying to override your link may break it at anytime as stated in [this post from recaptcha's support group](https://groups.google.com/g/recaptcha/c/XBhetkVgh84/m/pQTC5Sx6AgAJ)

Answer (score 1):

Using **recaptcha.net** for this problem is **NOT** going to solve the problem because it will again call back **google.com**.

So here I have one solution. The solution is using **cURL**. When you do requests from cURL it does not actually go from the client but it works as a **proxy** between the user and the server.

In PHP language you can do it in this way:

**reCaptcha.php**

```
<?php
if (! function_exists ( 'curl_version' )) {
    exit ( "Enable cURL in PHP" );
}


$ch = curl_init ();
$timeout = 0; // 100; // set to zero for no timeout
$myHITurl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha"; //domain which is blocked
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myHITurl );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "text=/");
$file_contents = curl_exec ( $ch );
if (curl_errno ( $ch )) {
    echo curl_error ( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );
    exit ();
}
curl_close ( $ch );

// dump output of api if you want during test
echo "$file_contents";
?>
```

So you can make a request to this **reCaptcha.php** file and use the **output** of this reCaptcha.php page as the **response**.

If you are not using PHP you can do this with your own project's programming language. You may also need some modification according to your need but you just need to use cURL, the process will remain the same.

But this will be very complex to implement. So, I would advise you to go for **another captcha service provider** like [hCaptcha](https://www.hcaptcha.com/) unless google itself fixes the request sending to google.com from recaptcha.net.

Comment: hCaptcha is expensive, asking for $99 per month, even expensive than my web hosting.